# Is there a way to add a treeview in CTk?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

Is there a method to add a treeview in tkinter? Like a class or something?

I tried to combine tkinter and CTk but I wasnt able to do that and I tried making a frame but the children of the nodes I put weren't showing up.

Comment: The tkinter.ttk module has a treeview. You add it like you add any other widget. Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all tkinter widgets with customtkinter. Just set the master ot the treeview as a ctk window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing

```
from tkinter import ttk
```